# SQL Multiple Main Tables Sharing A Common Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

We have a number of top level tables (e.g.,  room_traveler, air_traveler) which want to share a single table with common data (e.g., address_traveler).   The only way we can think to do this is to have the common table have a foreign key column for each top level table (e.g., address_traveler would have two foreign key columns, one for room_traveler and one for air_traveler).

This would work, but we expect to have more top level tables that need to use this common table.  This would mean we would have to continue adding foreign key columns to the common table for each new top level table.

I there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Why not have a `traveler_type` table and list all your travelers in one table with their respective types?

Comment: Hi! Because a traveler in a car has different columns (e.g. drivers license), than one for air (e.g. TSA information) and one for a room (e.g., smoking/non-smoking).  So each one is different.

Comment: So an air traveler can also be a room_traveler? And you want them to point to the same address?

Comment: I think you're looking at the relationship backwards, confusing IS/A vs HAS/A.  You have a person that travels.  So here is the information about the person.  Then he travels via air, so here is the information about his air travel.  A person HAS A non-smoking room.  rather than a person IS A non-smoking room.

Comment: Hi, no... I want a common table with a common set of columns that define an address.  One row would belong to a room traveler in booking A while another might belong to an air traveler in booking B.

Comment: Hi, regarding has-a vs is-a, I agree this is a has-a relationship (the traveler has an address). However I thought that in a relational database it is actually implemented in the reverse with the address having a foreign-key back to the traveler.

Comment: but dont you see that you have it set so that a traveler also IS A smoking room?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your point. The smoking room was just an example of why a room traveler is not an air traveler.  I'm focused on the traveler having an address (or even multiple addressses, e.g. a permanent address and a local address).

Comment: And a traveler should be able to have multiple addresses. In this situation I think you're fine.  Its the way you are handling air, room, and such.  What if the traveler just had a properties table, a columnar style table that you could add properties to to describe the traveler?

Comment: Good question.  There are situations where the keys/columns are dynamic and so using a key/value pair table makes sense, but in this case the columns are relatively static and allows us to maximize the use of the relational database we have.  Of course, we could go to a no-sql db, but that's not an option for us at this time.

Comment: Well, the address schema seems fine, but over all, I think this is a schema that will run into problems down the road.  Your types arent relational and could be, what if traveling by giraffe suddenly becomes popular. You'll have to add a `giraffe_traveler` table.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a good solution. It complicates queries and maintenance.

I am assuming that the address_traveler table contains addresses. Then give it a primary key... and id column. Then in the room_traveler and air_traveler tables (and any others that may come up in the future) you just add an address_id column that references the address_traveler table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Does that allow for a cascade delete,so that when the room_traveler row is deleted the associated address_traveler row would be deleted?  I know that some people don't like cascade delete, but in this case it makes sense.

Comment: No. In this case the child table would be the room_traveler and air_traveler tables. The address_traveler table is the parent. So you can only specify that a room_traveler or air_traveler child row be deleted on cascade of a parent address_traveler row. And I don't think that is what you want. Keep in mind that you could reference the same address from different child rows... so cascading the other way around does not make that much sense with this structure.